# How to update the nested array using useState Hook in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state, array-map

**I am getting the error [The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis]**
**Don't know how to update the nested array in useState.**

```
let tempArray = [
  {
    filterType: "Company",
    dataList: []
  },
  {
    filterType: "Vehicle",
    dataList: ["Car", "Bike"]
  }
]

const [resultList, setResultList] = useState(tempArray)
const [indexChange, setIndexChange] = useState(0)

// Assume here I am using fetch request and getting the response.
if (responseJson.success) {
  setResultList(
    [
      ...resultList, 
      resultList[indexChange].dataList: responseJson.data
    ]
  )
}
```

**Here I am rendering my result array. When clicking on the list! Based on the index, changes reflect.**

```
<div className='filterTypeContainer' style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F6F8", padding: "20px 20px", fontSize: 14, width: "40%" }}>
  { resultList.map((list, index) => { 
  return <div className='filerType' onClick={()=> setIndexChange(index)}>
    <p>{list.filterType}</p>
  </div>
  }) }
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with the expression `resultList[indexChange].dataList : responseJson.data` in an array?

Comment: Here I am trying to update the result array based on the (indexChange) which is 0 initially. But getting an error don't know how to update the nested array using destructure concept in javascript.

Comment: Yes but what is that row supposed to do? I don't think the destructuring is the problem but instead that row...

Comment: Suppose you have a list of different filters when you click on one filter based on that resultList updated through fetch request or temporary error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're using is called the spread operator `...value`. In this case it places all the items from the original state into a new array.

Use the spread operator to create a copy of the array. This prevents mutation to the original state. Then access the index in the array that you want to update and return the copied and updated state.

```
if (responseJson.success) {
  setResultList(resultList => {
    const copy = [...resultList]
    copy[indexChange].dataList = response.data
    return copy
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `.map` method to loop over the state and return an updated object based on the index.

```
if (responseJson.success) {
  setResultList(resultList => resultList.map((item, index) =>
    index === indexChange ? ({
      ...item,
      dataList: responseJson.data
    }) : item
  );
}
```